# SQL: Вывести все фамилии для каждого из имён

Tags: sql, база-данных, hql

Дана таблица:
[image: Исходная таблица]

В результате запроса нужно получить:
[image: Результат запроса]
Пожалуйста, подскажите текст запроса, который это может сделать

Comment: Только нативным SQL. Укажите точно используемую СУБД.

Comment: Akina, Apache Hive

Comment: Hive - всего лишь надстройка. С минимумом доступных агрегатных функций. Она обращается со своими запросами к внешней СУБД. Вот версия этой СУБД и нужна.